# Excel VBA MailEnvelope Selectively Not Working

Tags: vba, excel

I have run into an issue with Excel VBA's "MailEnvelope"

The file I am working on is stored in a network folder.  If I use my laptop to run it, I will either get the "Select method of Range class failed" error, or an error that says something about having network connectivity problems as soon as it hits the "With" portion of the code:

```
Sheets("Mail").Activate
Range("B10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Range("A3:C89").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False

ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True

With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
    .Introduction = "This is an automated message"
    .Item.To = "person@domain.com"
    .Item.Subject = "ActionList"
    .Item.Send
End With
```

This is quite frustrating for the following reasons:

- This code has worked perfectly for 2~3 months without issue
- This code still works perfectly if I step through it with F8 (for reasons I
  can't begin to fathom)
- This code still works perfectly if I run the file from a secondary computer.
- The "network connectivity" error really makes no sense since the "EnvelopeVisible" works fine, and the first line of the With statement is just trying to put text in the already visible introduction field.

Open to alternate solutions if the MailEnvelope method isn't particularly robust, just lost as to why it's suddenly having issues when the other computer isn't (both running Windows 7, Office 2010), and why it works if I step through it, but not if it's run normally.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try adding `ActiveWorkbook.Save` before the `with` block.  Seems this solves several issues reported by others, maybe it'll work for you too.

Comment: @PortlandRunner Gave it a shot this morning, no luck unfortunately.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Is it possible that the "Select method of Range class Failed" error that Excel is throwing me is something of a red herring and the actual problem has to do with limited resources?  The reason I ask: **1.)** The secondary computer I mentioned which can work through the code without issue has a faster processor and more memory. **2.)** There are a number of modules that run before it gets to this simple bit of code, and if I turn some of those other modules off it seems to work intermittently (no specific module has to be off, just fewer of them in general).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my follow-up question in the comment section, I have discovered that the error Excel was throwing me was indeed misleading.  I am now fairly confident that the issue I was having was one of limited resources; my assumption being that the MailEnvelope feature must be a bit more resource-intensive in its call to Outlook.  After a great deal of trial-and-error, the following steps have solved the issue for me completely:

- Moved the "Mailing" portion of the code to a separate module (which I am accessing simply via the "Call" command)
- Set ScreenUpdating to False
- Added a 10 second wait after the sending of the email

The final code, (again, now in a separate module) is as follows:

```
ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
    .Introduction = "This is an automated message"
    .Item.To = "person@domain.com"
    .Item.Subject = "ActionList"
    .Item.Send
End With

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
```

I have "stress-tested" this solution by running it multiple times, as well as trying it out in other code-heavy, large file-size workbooks, and it has been working perfectly thus far.